# How can I hide table if sql query displays no results

Tags: php, mysql, select

So i have been working on this query in order to display certain information depending on what is pulled from the database however I am always seeing the first  of the table which in this case are the table headers. My issue is when there are no results appearing the headers remain and have had no luck hiding them when the following queries produce no results. Please point me in the right direction and snippets can really help. :)

```
<div>
<?php
$query1 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1='$column1value'", OBJECT_K ));?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Header1</td>
            <td>Header2</td>
            <td>Header3</td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($query1 as $results1) {?>
            <?php if($results1->Column2 !="" && $results1->Column2_Msg!=""){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column1; ?></td>
                <td><?php if($results1->Column2!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column2)); }else echo '';?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column2_Msg; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
            <?php if($results1->Column3!="" && $results1->Column3!=""){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column1; ?></td>
                <td><?php if($results1->Column3!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column3)); }else echo '';?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column3_Msg; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
            <?php if($results1->Column4!="" && $results1->Column4_Msg!=""){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column1; ?></td>
                <td><?php if($results1->Column4!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column4)); }else echo '';?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results1->Column4_Msg; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping the tr which contains the header titles using the script below but that just hid them even if there were results for that area

```
 $verify = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT count(*) AS TALLY FROM table WHERE Column1='$column1value' AND Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column3 IS NOT NULL AND Column4 IS NOT NULL AND Column2_Msg  IS NOT NULL AND Column3_Msg IS NOT NULL AND Column4_Msg IS NOT NULL", OBJECT_K ));

 if ($verify->TALLY > 0 ) {
    foreach ($verify as $verified) {

    // html table goes here

    }
 }
 else {

    echo '';    
 }
```

can anyone shine some light on this one for me thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is the sql table structure and how it should and is working currently.

| group | location1 | location2 | location3 | location1_msg | location2_msg | location3_msg |

group column always has content
location1 and location1_msg, location2 and location2_msg as well as location3 and location3_msg,  are paired up in the html table and can have one or the other or both items populate.

so the html table could look like this

| header 1 | header 2  | header 3

|  group   | location1 |                                      |

|  group   | location2 | location2_msg                        |

|  group   |           | location3_msg                        |

however if there is nothing in the row for a group I don't want the html table to appear. I have everything working except getting it to go away lol

Comment: Hi, You can make a request count() before so that you don't make your request and you don't display the table if it returns 0.
Anyway, you should think about your application architecture to separate your data layer from your view.

Comment: still a bit wet behind the ears. do you have a link I can read about your suggestion by chance?

Comment: What else does the query show?

Comment: locations and messages, when there are no locations or messages inputted I need to hide the table. I am reviewing your code now as well.

Comment: what columns are they in..  We can add those columns to the if condition, or you can create a more strict query.

Comment: `<?php
$query_1_count = $wpdb-&gt;get_results( $wpdb-&gt;prepare ( &quot;SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE Column1=&#39;$column1value&#39;&quot;, OBJECT_K ));
if ($query_1_count > 0) { 
$query1= $wpdb-&gt;get_results( $wpdb-&gt;prepare ( &quot;SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1=&#39;$column1value&#39;&quot;, OBJECT_K ));
}
?>`

Comment: You can learn on MVC pattern on this link : https://bpesquet.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/evoluer-architecture-mvc/

There is also newer patterns like MVVM (Model vue vue model) ou MVP (Model vue presenter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same answer that M Khalid Junaid posted.  I just wanted to show you the script in it's entirety.  The reason being, and this is just personal preference, is that I personally don't like to break in and out of php so frequently through my code and especially across conditions.

So the code I have below shows you how you can break up your script with concatenation.  In my opinion it makes the script much more easy to follow and troubleshoot.

Anyways, just another way to do it:

```
$query1 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1='$column1value'", OBJECT_K ));

if($query1){

echo 
'<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Header1</td>
      <td>Header2</td>
      <td>Header3</td>
    </tr>';

    foreach ($query1 as $results1) {

      if($results1->Column2 !="" && $results1->Column2_Msg!=""){
      echo
        '<tr>
          <td>' . $results1->Column1 . '</td>';

          if($results1->Column2!=""){
          echo '<td>' . date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column2)) . '</td>'; 
          }
      echo '<td>' . $results1->Column2_Msg . '</td>
      </tr>';
      }

      if($results1->Column3!="" && $results1->Column3!=""){  
      echo  
      '<tr>
        <td>' . $results1->Column1 . '</td>';

        if($results1->Column3!=""){
        echo '<td>' . date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column3)) . '</td>'; 
        }

      echo '<td>' . $results1->Column3_Msg . '</td>
      </tr>';
      }  

      if($results1->Column4!="" && $results1->Column4_Msg!=""){
      echo  
      '<tr>
        <td>' . $results1->Column1 . '</td>';

        if($results1->Column4!=""){
        echo '<td>' . date('m/d/y', strtotime($results1->Column4)) . '</td>';
        }

        echo   '<td>' . $results1->Column4_Msg . '</td>
      </tr>';

      }
   }

  echo 
  '</table>
</div>';

} else{

  echo 'No data to display.';

  }
```

Comment: I updated my answer.  I forgot to add the closing table and div tags :)

Comment: going to play aropund with this and see if I can get it to work, will update my question if I need further help. Basically the table has 7 columns, one always has content and the other 6 can vary from either null values or not null (as in has content) basically when there is no data to pull from the 6 columns I want to hide the entire html table but if any of the 6 columns have data to pull then I need to display the table. The current query in my question I have populating the 6 columns in separate html table rows. maybe I need to wrap everything into a bit different more strict query?

Comment: @DigitalDesigner Show us the 7 column names.  Indicate which one always has content.

Comment: I am able to get the data populating using the code you provided but is still not hiding the headers when there are no results. so close yet so far lol story of my coding life ;)

Comment: Can you please update your question with your most current code.  I also am confused by the value your passing into query ($column1value).  This should only return rows that match the column 1 value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172937/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-digitaldesigner).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!empty` check before you create a table

```
<?php
$query1 = $wpdb->get_results(......);

    if(!empty($query1)){ ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
               ...............
            <tr>
        </table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: the issue is technically the query is always not empty as there is always content in Column1, maybe I need to change the select * to a more specific query?

Comment: @DigitalDesigner I assume you want to display table if your query returns data, If there is some other criteria to show/hide table the put this  check inside if clause